# How to implement Paybox deferred payment?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

How do I integrate paybox system to handle deferred payment?

I learned that `PBX_DIFF` parameter is used to mention no. of days to delay the transaction. Thats exactly what I wanted. But there seems no working code for php with deferred payment for Paybox.

The following code is working fine without mentioning the deferred payment parameter (`PBX_DIFF`). But when I add that parameter, its not working

```
<form name="paybox_frm" id="paybox_frm"  method="GET" action="<?php echo $payboxUrl;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_SITE" value="<?php echo $PBX_SITE; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_RANG" value="<?php echo $PBX_RANG; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_IDENTIFIANT" value="<?php echo $PBX_IDENTIFIANT; ?>">
<input type="hidden"  name="PBX_TOTAL" value="<?PHP echo $MONTANT;?>">
<input type="hidden"  name="PBX_DEVISE" value="<?php echo $PBX_DEVISE; ?>">
<input type="hidden"  name="PBX_CMD" value="<?PHP echo $REFERENCE;?>">
<input type="hidden"  name="PBX_PORTEUR" value="<?PHP echo $PORTEUR;?>">
<input type="hidden"  name="PBX_RETOUR" value="<?php echo $PBX_RETOUR;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_HASH" value="<?php echo $PBX_HASH;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_TIME" value="<?PHP echo $datetime;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_HMAC" value="<?PHP echo $pbx_hmac;?>">

<!-- Code added for return url-->

<input type="hidden" name="PBX_REFUSE" value="<?PHP echo $PBX_REFUSE;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_ANNULE" value="<?PHP echo $PBX_ANNULE;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_EFFECTUE" value="<?PHP echo $PBX_EFFECTUE;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="PBX_LANGUE" value="<?PHP echo $PBX_LANGUE;?>" />
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="rl-box">
    <div class="container padd-xs-0">
        <div class="content-section1">
            <div class="left-cont col-md-12 col-sm-12"
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <?php
                    $PBX_SITE = "1999888";
                    $PBX_RANG = "32";
                    $PBX_IDENTIFIANT = "your identifiant id";
                    $secretKeyTest = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";
                    $PBX_PORTEUR = "your-email";
                    $PAYBOX_DOMAIN_SERVER = "tpeweb.paybox.com";
                    $dateTime = date("c");

                    $PBX_TOTAL = 4000; //$_POST["PBX_TOTAL"];   // Amount
                    $PBX_DEVISE = 978;
                    //$PBX_CMD = $_POST["PBX_CMD"]."|".$_POST["user"]."|".$_POST["typed"]."|".$_POST["period"]."|".$_POST["id"]; // order ID no.                          
                    $PBX_CMD = 1; // order ID no.


                    $PBX_RETOUR = "Mt:M;Ref:R;Auto:A;Erreur:E";
                    $PBX_HASH = "SHA512";
                    $PBX_TIME = $dateTime;

                    //$PBX_EFFECTUE = "http://www.leader-underwriting.eu/payment/payment.php";

                    $msg = "PBX_SITE=$PBX_SITE" .
                            "&PBX_RANG=$PBX_RANG" .
                            "&PBX_IDENTIFIANT=$PBX_IDENTIFIANT" .
                            "&PBX_TOTAL=$PBX_TOTAL" .
                            "&PBX_DEVISE=$PBX_DEVISE" .
                            "&PBX_CMD=$PBX_CMD" .
                            "&PBX_PORTEUR=$PBX_PORTEUR" .
                            "&PBX_RETOUR=$PBX_RETOUR" .
                            "&PBX_HASH=$PBX_HASH" .
                            "&PBX_TIME=$PBX_TIME";


                    $binKey = pack("H*", $secretKeyTest);
                    $hmac = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha512', $msg, $binKey));

                    $cuu = str_replace(",", "", $ramount);
                    ?>                             
                    <form method="POST" name="form_payment" action="https://preprod-tpeweb.paybox.com/cgi/MYchoix_pagepaiement.cgi">

                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_SITE" value="<?php echo $PBX_SITE; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_RANG" value="<?php echo $PBX_RANG; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_IDENTIFIANT" value="<?php echo $PBX_IDENTIFIANT; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_TOTAL" value="<?php echo $PBX_TOTAL; ?>"> <!--dynamic-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_DEVISE" value="<?php echo $PBX_DEVISE; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_CMD" value="<?php echo $PBX_CMD; ?>">  <!--dynamic-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_PORTEUR" value="<?php echo $PBX_PORTEUR ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_RETOUR" value="<?php echo $PBX_RETOUR; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_HASH" value="<?php echo $PBX_HASH; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_TIME" value="<?php echo $PBX_TIME; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="PBX_HMAC" value="<?php echo $hmac; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary payment">
                            Payer
                        </button> 
                    </form>
                    <center>

                    </center>

                </div>

            </div>


        </div> <!-- .container-fluid -->

    </div>               

</div>
</div>
</section>
```